# Moving text on the screen using pygame keyboard

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to move text on the left or right of the screen using the keyboard arrows but could not get it to work. My code is:

```
while True :

    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 20) # Font type # Font style 
    frame = pygame.display.set_mode ((Renderer.CANVAS_WIDTH, Renderer.CANVAS_HEIGHT))

    frame.fill ((49,33,148))

    for event in pygame.event.get ():
        if event.type == QUIT :
            pygame.quit ()
            sys.exit    ()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN :

                f = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 20) # Font type # Font style 
                Track = font.render("Track : ", True, (255,255,0) )



    Game ()
    pygame.draw.rect(frame, (30,21,95),(50,400,700,170)) # draw a blue box on the screen 
    Track = font.render("Track : ", True, (255,255,0) )
    frame.blit(Track,(80,410))

    Labs = font.render ("Labs :", True, (255,255,0))
    frame.blit(Labs,(80,440))

    Distance = font.render ("Distance :", True, (255,255,0))
    frame.blit(Distance,(80,480))


    pygame.display.update ()  # Update the screen 






pygame.quit ()
quit ()
```

Comment: Why do you have spaces in between a method's name and its parentheses? Also, how did it "not work"?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code to move text around with the keyboard using pygame

```
f = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 20) # Font type # Font style 
Track = font.render("Track : ", True, (255,255,0) )

xpos = 10
ypos = 10

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                ypos -= 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                ypos += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                xpos -= 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                xpos += 5

    frame.fill((255, 255, 255))
    frame.blit(Track, (xpos, ypos))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

However this will only work when you press the key, it won't let you hold it down. To do that it's a little more complex. See:

```
f = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 20) # Font type # Font style 
Track = font.render("Track : ", True, (255,255,0) )

moveUp = False
moveDown = False
moveRight = False
moveLeft = Falsed

xpos = 10
ypos = 10

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                moveDown = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                moveRight = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                moveDown = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                moveRight = False

    if moveUp:
        ypos -= 5
    elif moveDown:
        ypos += 5
    if moveLeft:
        xpos -= 5
    elif moveRight:
        xpos += 5

    frame.fill((255, 255, 255))
    frame.blit(Track, (xpos, ypos))
    pygame.display.flip()
```